# Python plugin architecture where plugins are packages

Tags: python, plugins, python-importlib

I am trying to create a python application that can be extended with plugins.

For testing I've tried to create a plugin with the following structure:

```
plugin_name
├── __init__.py
├── utils.py
└── config.py
```

The plugin class that I need is located in `plugin_name.__init__.py`, but `___init__.py` uses `utils.py`.

I am using the following code to import `__init__.py`:

```
import os

module_path = "path to __init__.py"
package_name = os.path.basename( os.path.dirname(path) )
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(package_name, path)
plugin_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)

spec.loader.exec_module(plugin_module )
```

If `__init__.py` imports `utils.py` as such:

```
import utils.py
```

It throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

If `__init__.py` imports `utils.py` as such:

```
import utils.py
```

It throws `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

So it's obvious that the import code I'm using doesn't recognize the package and only imports the specific file I specify without any metadata of the folder it is in or the other files in the same directory.

Is there a way to import packages like this?

---

I'm looking into `pkgutil` and I can see that using `pkgutil.walk_modules`, I can identify all the packages in the plugin. I'm wondering if I can use this to import the plugins I want, but I can't find any examples or documentation that would suggest this.

Comment: This is not usually how to make a project "pluggable". Unless the plugins are installed while the Python process is already running. Is that your case?

Comment: Yes the plugins exist in a folder called plugins and I have the paths leading to each plugin.

Comment: Actually, could you clarify what you mean by installed? I don't have them pip installed, but they exist in a known directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin directory looks as such:

```
path_to_plugin
└── plugin_name
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── utils.py
    └── config.py
```

```
import pkgutil

path = 'path_to_plugin'

modules = []
for package in pkgutil.iter_modules(path):
    finder, name, ispkg = package
    spec = finder.find_spec(name)
    module = spec.loader.load_module(name)
    modules.append(module)
```

This code loads packages dynamically inside a directory.

If there is a better answer, please share.